# Is it possible to build default ECG like app in WatchOS?

Tags: healthkit, watchos

Native ECG App in Apple Watch shows real time ecg as timeseries graph.
Is there any possible function to achive same things on ECG or PPG signal as real-time timeseries data?

As far as I found, the HealthKit libraries only supports 'calculated' numbers of HR, HRV indices... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get real-time data when user is taking an ECG. However, you can see time series data for an ECG that was taken by the user and saved in HealthKit. See the [HKElectrocardiogram](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkelectrocardiogram) data type and [HKElectrocardiogramQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkelectrocardiogramquery) to access the voltage measurements of the ECG sample.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's really unfortunate. Based on this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940626/apple-health-initheartbeatseries-how-to-get-hkheartbeatseriessample), it cannot be 'extract' with second-level period the user defined. right?

Comment: ECG and heartbeat series are separate data types. You should query and see what data you're getting back from HKElectrocardiogramQuery and if that's sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much, actually, any data of that query seems not sufficient. since I want to real-time(immediate) feedback when new heart cycle starts(Of course there would be a little delay (xx ms)).  For example, the peak value of PPG signal or R peak (or whatever other peak) of ECG, just like the raw ECG line drawn in Apple ECG app.

Comment: It's monopole. apple should open door for other developers